# Signal slot not working

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I have worked with signals and slots before and never had any problem, but right now a new connection I made is not working. I can't understand what I am doing wrong.

This is my Listener.hpp:

```
class Listener : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //explicit Listener(QObject *parent = 0);
    explicit Listener();
    void listen();
    void stopListen();
    bool isListening();

public slots:
    void on_newConnection();
    void on_readyRead();
    void on_disconnected();

signals:
    void readyToReadFromServer();

private:
    QTcpServer* m_server;
    QTcpSocket* m_socket;

};
```

This is my Listener.cpp:

```
Listener::Listener()
{
    m_server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(m_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(on_newConnection()));
}

void Listener::listen()
{

    string strPort = ConfigManager::instance().get("Channel.Port");
    QString qstrPort(strPort.c_str());
    qint16 port = qstrPort.toUInt();

    m_server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, port);

    //QCoreApplication::instance()->exec();

}
void Listener::stopListen()
{
    m_server->close();
}
bool Listener::isListening()
{
    return m_server->isListening(); 
}
void Listener::on_newConnection()
{
    m_socket = m_server->nextPendingConnection();

    if(m_socket->state() == QTcpSocket::ConnectedState)
    {
        printf("New connection established.\n");
    }

    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(on_readyRead()));
    connect(m_socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(on_disconnected()));   
}

void Listener::on_readyRead()
{
    emit readyToReadFromServer();
}

void Listener::on_disconnected()
{
        //...
}
```

I use the `Controller` class to connect all signals - slots in my app and several other things.

This is my Controller.hpp in short (this class has lots of method, signal - slot and they are irrelevant to this problem, so I didn't mention them):

```
class  Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void waitForCommands();
    ...
signals:    
    void greeting_send();
    ...
private:
    Listener m_listener;
}
```

I connect all signal - slot in the following method:

```
bool Controller::init()
{
    ...
    this->connect(&m_listener, SIGNAL(readyToReadFromServer()), SLOT(waitForCommands()));
    ...
}
```

Also there is the `waitForCommands()` method in this class:

```
void Controller::waitForCommands()
{
    ...
}
```

I connected all my project's slots and signals like this and all of them are working, but not this one. How do I fix this?

Comment: Your code shows no signs of slot function `waitForCommands` except in the connect call. Did you checked the application output? Is there maybe an error message about a failed connect?

Comment: Do you know, that 'connect' returns a parameter? Boolean. Helps tremendously to figure out if a connect fails or succeeds. Amazing, I read plenty of code, but I rarely see this return value used.

Comment: @Roku   :  There is waitForCommands() method i just didn't mention it here and 5 other signal connected to it already and working fine so im sure my Slot have no problem

Comment: @Greenflow : I know that already and i did check and it was true

Comment: I don't see any problem with this code. But of course it is possible that I overlook something. I suppose you called 'listen' in Listener? Put some output in Listener's constructor. It is certainly executed, but only once? You get the "New connection established" message? on_readyRead() is called?

Comment: @Greenflow : Yes, on_readyRead() is called but when it goes to emit its not working

Comment: I made a few change and its working now but i don't want it to work this way, I did "m_listener = new m_listener()" then used it to connect my signal slots and now its working